# New type dynamically based on other type

Tags: typescript

I want to dynamically create a type based on another one or on readonly array.
Example:

```
const lines = ['one', 'two', 'three'] as const;
const linesWithA = lines.map(line => `${line}-A`);
```

Now I need a way to have a type for `linesWithA`. It can be for example a union type `'one-A' | 'two-A' | 'three-A'`, but it needs to be generated dynamically. So when I will manualy add an element to  `lines`, then I don't have to remember to change it for `linesWithA` type.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `as const` specifier within the map statement, then you can simply get all of the line types by indexing that array with `number` to get the items.

```
const lines = ['one', 'two', 'three'] as const;
const linesWithA = lines.map(line => `${line}-A` as const);
type LineWithA = typeof linesWithA[number]; // "one-A" | "two-A" | "three-A"
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgSzAUwjAvDA2gcnMnAGhhygHcQiSoALAJ2QIF0YBDNUSKAbgChPo8JKgDqCWgEEMQlBAB0AW1YAHABSIUGAHwwABgBIA3huQBfALQTdbDuGgBKPlACey5DAAywsZOku3IABmMqLiNBJYYACuCgBGyHRM3EA)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible:

```
type lines = 'one' | 'two' | 'three'
type linesWithA = `${lines}-A`
```

This feature of TypeScript is called [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html), and it was introduced in version [4.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/).

You can try the example above on the
[TS Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBANglgOwgZygXigcgPZM1AHy2AHdt8jNgALAJwgkwChRJZEUB1OGgQXSgADACQBveEmQBfALS9BQA)

Comment: Thanks! It's a pity I can't mark more answers as accepted ones.